# Installing gnu plot for macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, gnuplot

How does one install a runnable version of gnu plot in macOS high Sierra?
I am looking for a way to make this work with the GUI, but even just getting the terminal script to run would be a success.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome aboard. Here, we share our codes or our errors to get helped. If you provide some codes or some errors, someone can help you.

Comment: Kindly read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Install `brew` system and then `gnuplot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough with **homebrew**.

First, install Xcode command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then install **homebrew** by going to [homebrew website](https://brew.sh) and copying and pasting the one-liner installation script. I don't want to paste that line here in case it changes down the line, so get the latest from the homebrew website.

Now you have a full package manager that allows you to find, install, update and delete thousands of packages. So you can easily find **gnuplot** or anything else with:

```
brew search gnuplot
```

Once you have found your package, check the avaiable options with:

```
brew options gnuplot
```

**Sample Output**

```
--with-aquaterm
    Build with AquaTerm support
--with-cairo
    Build the Cairo based terminals
--with-qt
    Build with qt support
--with-wxmac
    Build wxmac support. Need with-cairo to build wxt terminal
--with-x11
    Build with x11 support
```

Now install with some sensible options for graphical plots:

```
brew install gnuplot --with-qt --with-x11
```

Always ensure your PATH starts with `/usr/local/bin` for **homebrew** since that is where it installs programs. I put the following in `$HOME/.profile`. And I also set the `GNUTERM` environment variable:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export GNUTERM=qt
```

Now run **gnuplot**:

```
gnuplot
```

**Sample Run**

[image]

Check out many useful packages, a nice new Python not Apple's old v2.7, a nice Linux-compatible `sed` not Apple's BSD version, a nice `grep`, a nice `find`, the brilliant GNU awk, **ImageMagick**, `tmux`, **GNU Parallel**, `jhead`, Poppler, `exiftool`, Mosquitto, `pdfgrep`, `pngcrush`, ZeroMQ... the list goes on...

Comment: Yup. this does it. I would install Aquaterm after XQuartz but before gnuplot and install gnuplot with: brew install gnuplot --with-qt --with-x11 --with-aquaterm. The Aquaterm terminal misses some features but easily produces 'prettier' plots. One can always switch between installed terminals.

Comment: This all seemed to work, thanks. Could you go into a bit more detail on how all the packages work together and what their specific roles are. Thanks again, very helpful.

Comment: @DanSp. Glad you like the answer. I have not tried Aquaterm but will give it a try on your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I used gnu plot on scientific Linux and it seems to be a stand-alone program that shows its own plots. On MacOS, all these different packages are needed to display the plots properly. Why is this so? I thought that since MAcOS and Linux are cousins it'd be much closer. My question remains, what are all the different options listed and why are they needed in the first place? (like qt, x11, AquaTerm..etc). Thanks again

Comment: Linux machines are pretty much standardised on using X11 to display graphics. MacOS, however, split and went a different way. Apple no longer ship an X11 server, and they developed Carbon and Cocoa frameworks for graphics. I guess that means gnuplot had to be ported away from X11, and different ports adopted different graphics engines, so you have a choice. I'd take that as a positive. If it upsets you, just choose one and run with that, ignoring the others.

Answer (score 2):

The Brew implementation of gnuplot is not really usable because it no longer supports the necessary terminals (e.g., you can no longer provide --with-aquaterm or --with-x11 during installation).

However, the MacPorts package manager has a usable install for gnuplot (it's safe to have both Brew and MacPorts installed). https://www.macports.org/

After intalling AquaTerm, I used the following to install gnuplot, and all is working as expected:

`sudo port install gnuplot +aquaterm`

I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Answer (score 0):

@David Atri: gnuplot is not as standalone as you might think. Try to compile it from source and you will see how many options and dependencies it has.The main challenge in MacOSX is to get the PDF drivers running. The fact that you see many things as standalone is the good integration work made by the developers

Answer (score 0):

brew is no longer support options.

You can still do "brew install gnuplot", but it will install with just the terminals that the person who wrote the homebrew formula wanted, not necessarily the ones you want.

Compiling gnuplot from the sources is still a nightmare, so you live with the brew-formula writer's choices, write your own brew formula (not completely trivial), or you struggle with huge pile of dependencies and try to compile from the sources.

Comment: Thanks for the info!